# вызвать функцию не чаще одного раза в 3 сеекуннд

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Цитата

При клике вызывается функция которая меняет слайд. Изменение слайда происходить с анимацией где то 1-2 сек. И получается так что если пользователь несколько раз подряд кликнет то если он перестанет кликать будут еще выполняться предыдущие клики. Не знаю. как правильно сформировать вопрос, примерно нужно сделать так чтобы после первого клика второй работал когда слайд изменился, а клики которые были сделаны во время когда слайд меняйся не работали

```
$('#slider')
        .css({
            width: '80%',
            margin: 'auto'
        })
        .append(`<div id="slide"></div>`)
        .append(`<div id="progress-bar"></div>`)
        .click(function(event) {
            changeBackground(event.pageX > $('body').width() / 2 ? 1 : -1)
        });

    let i = 1;
    function changeBackground(dir) {
       
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            widthPercent += widthPercentAdd * dir;
            i += dir;
            if (i > 5) {
                i = 1;
                widthPercent = widthPercentAdd;
            };
            if (i < 1) {
                i = 5;
                widthPercent = 100;
            };
            $('#slide')
            .fadeOut(() => {
                $('#slide').css({
                    background: `url("img/${i}.png") center/cover`,
                })
            })
            .fadeIn();
            $('#progress-bar__item').css({
                width: `${widthPercent}%`,  
            });
            changeCount();
            myInterval = setInterval(myTimer, 3000);
        
    };
```

Comment: Предоставьте больше кода, например функцию `changeBackground`

Comment: Добавил выше , внутри setinterval это у меня слайд меняется сам каждые три секунды после клика удаляю ее чтобы если интервал и клик одновременно будут не было багов, changeCount это функ счетсик слайдера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создай переменную внутри функции, которая будет сообщать о статусе слайдера. Если он в процессе, то `return`, если нет, то запускаем код дальше.

```
// создаем глобальную переменную
let sliderInProcess = false;

function changeBackground(dir) {
        // не запускаем анимацию, если еще в процессе
        if (sliderInProcess) return;

        // ставим статус в процессе
        sliderInProcess = true;  
        
        // код анимации
        
        // через 3 секунды ставим false в статус
        setTimer(() => sliderInProcess = false, 3000);
    
};
```

Comment: myInterval = setInterval(() => sliderInProcess = false, 3000);  это как понимаю время выполнение изменение слайда?

Comment: Sorry, поправил свой код. Нам потребуется setTimer, который через 3 секунды поменяет значение глобальной переменной

Comment: спасибо большое, в принципе можно было в fadeIn выполнить callback функ .fadeIn(function() {
                sliderInProcess = false
            }); которое после выполнение fadeIN сделает переменную false, пока багов не обнаружил работает, ваш ответ помог разобраться как сделать, спасибо)